# How do you get past this room in 3-6?

Tags: standby

I've gotten to a room in STANDBY that I cannot figure out how to get through. Here's a screenshot of the room:

[image: Screenshot of the game in the room in question.]

Pictured in the screenshot is as far up the wall as I'm able to get. I can't jump high enough to reach the blue wall on the left, and I can't run fast enough to get to the blue wall on the right.

How do you get through this room?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just dash at the wall, you'll get to the height in the picture in the question.

If you *jump* on the uphill section as you're dashing towards the wall, then you'll reach higher on the wall. This trick is also necessary in later levels in world 3, and under tighter time constraints.